# Why is there a vertical scrollbar, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css

I have an html structure styled with css and i don't understand why there is a scollbar / the browser thinks there is an overflow. I tested this in current Chrome and IE11.

The HTML is basically like this:

```
<div id="DIV_1">
    <div id="DIV_2">
        <div id="DIV_3">
            <!-- some tables, some content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The (important) css is as follows:

```
#DIV_1 {
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 545px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#DIV_2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 545px;
}

#DIV_3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

`DIV_3` now gets a scrollbar and i don't understand why it happens.

Please see the corresponding [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orp4g5yj/) for more details.

EDIT: **I do know how to hide a scrollbar with overflow: hidden! This is not what i want to do.**

Comment: did you use a css reset? Try this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or just html, body {margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: Yes i do use a html5 css reset. However in this case every existing css property is contained in the JsFiddle.

Comment: @JonasGrumann Seems you do have some knowledge about css. Could you possibly have a closer look to the problem?

Comment: Please strip down your CSS to what is exactly necessary to reproduce this problem. Now you've got a lot of overhead: get rid of all `transform`, `color`, optimize and `0` based values. They don't add anything. I don't understand your CSS management either. This is not how you ought to construct your CSS files. Also, don't use decimal pixel values. Browsers differ in how they deal with those which can cause broken layouts.

Comment: I'll try. The css shown in the fiddle is generated by a tool called "SnappySnipped" which allows to extract and isolate HTML and css from web pages. The problem is that i can't really use the "real" css because it is also generated from less files and so on. But i'll try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#TD_113 {
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px
}
```

is the cause. However it's not the `30px`, it's because the `padding-bottom` has been reset to `0px`. Chrome's default seems to be `td { padding: 1px }` and setting

```
#TD_113 {
    padding: 0px 30px 1px 0px
}
```

seems to fix it for me. I can only think that the combination of the `height: 13px` no `padding-bottom` is causing the containing element to be *smaller* than the content and therefore the scollbar appears to allow you to scroll to see the content. Alternatively changing to `font-size: 14px` on the `<td>` or parent `<tr>` and leaving the padding alone also removes the scrollbar.

**Update:** I created a [much shorter example](http://jsfiddle.net/h8wdk8o9/) of the problem in which I can see a scrollbar in Chrome. I now believe that setting `border-spacing` to `0px` is causing the problem in this case, although the `padding` issue on your fiddle is still the CSS I need to edit in order to remove the scrollbar.

```css
#DIV_2 {
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
#DIV_3 {
    overflow: auto;
}
#TABLE_110 {
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV_2">
    <div id="DIV_3">
        <table id="TABLE_110">
            <tbody id="TBODY_111">
                <tr id="TR_112">
                    <td colspan="4" id="TD_113">10.03.2015</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if i don't really get why this is happening, this seems to be where things are coming from. Adding a padding in the original code also fixes the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, the problem is with the property overflow:auto; it means that whenever the content is larger than the container, the scrollbar must be shown, so just remove the property.

Answer (score 0):

Logically the reason you're getting a vertical scrollbar is that the browser interprets the content to have a height which is bigger then the height of container...

in this case you're having vertical margins which overflow and are not being cleared;

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/orp4g5yj/2/) resetting to `margin:0` and the `overflow-Y` disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

```
#DIV_1 {
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#DIV_2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 545px;
}

#DIV_3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Removed the width property and it worked.